# Azure DevOps I deleted Microsoft-hosted Agent by API how can I recreate this kind of agent?

Tags: azure-devops

[image: Printscreen of Azure Devops - Agent pool]

When we deleted this agent all pipelines that use Microsoft-hosted throw this kind of error.

```
##[error]No agent found in pool Azure Pipelines which satisfies the specified demands: Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1
```

We don't have any option to create the agent Microsoft-hosted on the portal, so someone knows how could we resolve this issue?

Comment: We resolved. When I increased microsoft-hosted agents parallel automatically the agents appeared on agent list...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your sharing. You can add the comment as answer and accept it. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution, or according to your description, I have tested it and share the steps below, you can also check it.
In addition, could you please share the detail steps to delete the agent via API, I tried it and get the error Access Denied. Microsoft-hosted agent pools cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

Login Organization Settings->Billing->set up billing->check the tab Pipeline for private projects and enter the number in the field Paid parallel jobs->Wait a few minutes then the agents appeared on agent list.

Result:

[image]